# Why is the Default Screen layout not showing all objects?

Tags: objects, 3d-view

Whenever I change the layout to Default, it only shows one object. Do you have any idea why?
[image: animation layout]

[image: default layout with only one object showing]

Comment: Is it possible that the rest of the objects you want to see are on other layers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the screenshots you posted, you can see that in the top-left corner it says "User Ortho *(Local)*", which means you are in *Local View* mode. Just press <kbd>NumPad /</kbd> to toggle it.

Comment: Saved my life. 10/10